# Telerik MVC checkbox row selection

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using **Telerik MVC Grid**. I would like to know how to select/unselect a row when the user checks/unchecks a checkbox and have it persist on page changes.  Below is what I have. Please note I am not using the Kendo Grid as here is a link to exactly what I want: [Kendo Example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Selection/grid-selection-checkbox)

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TrialProductViewModel>().Name("products")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Selected).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' onclick='editCurrentCell(this)'  name='Selected' #= Selected? checked='checked' : '' # />")
          columns.Bound(c => c.ProductType).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity).Filterable
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Selectable(selectable =>
      {
          selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple);
          selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
          selectable.Enabled(false);
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(p => p.ItemDescription);
          })
      .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Trial")))
      .Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
)

<script>
function editCurrentCell(element) {
    $("#products").data("kendoGrid").one("edit", function (e) {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        if (e.model.Selected) {
            //-remove selection
            row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
            e.model.set("Selected", false);
        }
        else {
            //-select the row
            row.addClass("k-state-selected");
            e.model.set("Selected", true);
        }
        //For testing purpose only
        console.log(e.model.Selected);
    });
    $("#products").data("kendoGrid").editCell($(element).closest("td"));
}

// this will select any rows where the checkbox is checked on data bound event
function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = this;
    var currentRecords = grid.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentRecords.length; i++) {
        //currentRecords[i] is the current dataItem 
        if (currentRecords[i].Selected) {
            grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentRecords[i].uid + "']").addClass("k-state-selected");
        }
    }
}
// this allows for selecting multiple rows without having to hold down the ctrl key
// also note in order for this to work you need to set selectable.Enabled(false);
$("#products").delegate('tbody>tr', 'click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('k-state-selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the state of the checkbox and then set the class accordingly

```
$("#gridName").on("click", ".checkbox", function () {
    var checked = this.checked,
    row = $(this).closest("tr"),
    grid = $("#gridName").data("kendoGrid"),
    dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    checkItems[dataItem.id] = checked;

    if (checked) {
        $("tr[data-tableId='" + $(row).data("tableId") + "']").addClass("k-state-selected");
    } 
    else {
        $("tr[data-tableId='" + $(row).data("tableId") + "']").removeClass("k-state-selected");
    }
});
```